# ¿Cómo puedo crear un array de tipo Articulo en la clase principal?

Tags: php

La pregunta es como puedo realizar un array, en java si se hacerlo, es `ArrayList<Clase> nombreArray = new ArrayList<Clase>();` pero en PHP no se realizarlo. Tengo 1 clase, llamada Articulo y en la página principal quiero tener un array de todos los artículos que el usuario ha seleccionado para realizar el pedido.
Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP es un lenguaje [débilmente tipado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte#Lenguajes_no_tipados). Cuando defines los arrays, no tienes que declarar lo que va en cada elemento:

```
// Define tu clase
class Articulo { }

// Define el array
$arr = [];

// Añade elementos al array
$arr[] = new Articulo();
```

De hecho podrías seguir añadiendo otros tipos de elementos a este array (strings, números, cualquier otro objeto...)

Comment: Sin embargo no hay que conformarse con que PHP sea *débilmente tipado* y dar rienda suelta a un estilo de programación donde mezcles de todo. PHP 7 empezó a restringir ciertas cosas y resulta que ahora mucho código escrito basándose en esa supuesta libertad de PHP empieza a fallar a partir de PHP 7. Es recomendable escribir nuestros programas renunciando a esa *aparente* libertad que ofrece PHP, intentando una declaración estricta de los objetos y de sus miembros.